# Controller não carrega Angular + RequireJS

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

Estou desenvolvendo uma arquitetura para trabalhar com Angular em uma aplicação de grande porte com MVC AspNet, neste aplicação não será o Angular que ira tratar as rotas, mas sim o AspNet, então nesta arquitetura eu não vou ter routes do Angular.

Todas as páginas tem o seu próprio entrypoint Ex: group.entrypoint.js, que é este trecho de código:

```
//Load common code that includes config, then load the app logic.
'use strict';

(function () {
    require(['./entrypoint'], function () {

        //Group Controller
        require(['./controllers/group.controller']);
    });
})();
```

Que vai para este entrypoint global da aplicação (entrypoint.js):

```
//Global EntryPoint

var paths = {
    global:      './',
    angular:     './assets/vendor/angular/' 
};

require.config({
    name: 'App EntryPoint',
    baseUrl: '',
    paths: {
        'config':           paths.global + 'config/config',
        'angular':          paths.angular + 'angular.min', 
        'angular-route':    paths.angular + 'angular-ui-router.min',
        'angular-sanitize': paths.angular + 'angular-sanitize.min'              
    },
    shim: {     
        'angular-route': {
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angular-sanitize': {
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'angular'
        },      
        angular: {
            exports : 'angular'
        }
    },
    deps: ['config']
});
```

Depois tenho este config (config.js):

```
'use strict';

define(['angular', 'angular-route', 'angular-sanitize'], function (angular, route, sanitize) {

    var app = angular.module('app', ['route', 'sanitize']);

    // Bootstrap Application
    angular.bootstrap(app);

    return app; 
});
```

Pois bem, e na minha controller tenho este trecho de código, a idéia que quero é dar um require na Factory ou Service quando precisar e usar dentro da controller:

```
'use strict';

define(['config'], function (app) {

    (function () {

        //Global Services
        var service = require(['./services/services']);

        //Group Factory
        var factory = require(['./factories/group.factory']);               

        app.controller('groupController', groupController);

        groupController.$inject = ['$scope', 'service', 'factory'];

        function groupController($scope, service, factory) {
            $scope.name = 'foo';
        }

        return groupController;

    })();   
});
```

Bem o que acontece é que nada acontece, ele passa pelo script da controller do grupo, mas não faz nada, por exemplo na tela tenho `ng-controller="groupController as group"` na tag body, mas ele não da o "bind" do que está na controller, então gostaria de saber o que de fato está errado ? Ou, se este modo que estou fazendo também não é o mais correto ?

Alguém ja passou por algo semelhante ?

Comment: Estou com um problema semelhante usando o AngularJS com o RequireJS, o problema meu é que `as vezes` o controller carrega e as vezes fica esperando ser carregado. De um olhadinha no meu [github-angularjs-requirejs](https://github.com/ralfting/angular-require)